# How i set same name variable multiple

Tags: javascript, web

I'm setting up variable, and want to put two option settings into one variable.

i want to 'admin' variable set of popadmin, admin

i set like this code

```
var CHAT_CONFIG = {
 'admin' : 'popadmin', 'admin', //Admin member ID's
 'member_max' : 1000, //max member
 'expire_time' : 600, //chat delete time
 'chatlog_max' : 30 //previous chat log 
}
```

but did't work well.

i had an error

I expect the admin variable set of popadmin admin but the actual result an error

Comment: {admin: ['admin', 'popadmin']}

Comment: Reading the error message would be a good start.  As would examining the code which produces the error.

Comment: this is full code
var CHAT_CONFIG = {
    'admin'        :  'popadmin', 'admin', //Admin member ID's
    'member_max'  : 1000, //max member
    'expire_time' : 600, //chat delete time
    'chatlog_max' : 30 //previous chat log
}

@AZ_ I tried that .. but still didn't work ..

Comment: @BootRe: That's different from the code you're showing in the question.  Please *update the question* and *clarify* what your code is and what the problem is.

Comment: @David okay sorry

I'll update code

Comment: @BootRe I don't see a reason why `admin: ['admin', 'popadmin']` will not work, update your que with this ans and error.

Comment: @AZ_ it works! thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax for setting a variable is invalid:

```
'admin' : 'popadmin', 'admin'
```

If you want an array of values, you need to enclose the array in brackets:

```
'admin' : ['popadmin', 'admin']
```

---

Note that in your original code before updating the question you also had a valid syntax, though less likely to be what you want:

```
'admin' : 'popadmin, admin'
```

In this case the *syntax* is valid, but the difference is that this creates a single *string* instead of an *array* of strings.

---

Which of the two you want is up to you and how you use these values.  It's very likely that an array is warranted here.  I would even go so far as to argue that, if for some reason this component *does* want a delimited string, it should be modified to accept an array.

> "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." -Eric Raymond